# How to store Parse[dot]com application data

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using Parse.com with android backed app and wanted to store some of data specific to application not user's data.

So, is there anyway I can accomplish this without login in any user & store data which belong to app not user.

Answer (score 1):

Sure..  You can create and query objects on Parse regardless of whether you're logged in or not.  You can also call cloud functions.

I would recommend using a Cloud Function, locking down the security of the classes you're using to store the data, and using the Master Key in the cloud function to access/write to the data securely.

Comment: Fosco, I have initialized parse library, and when saving the object getting following exception.

ParseObject message = new ParseObject("MessageStore");
exception thrown over the constructor line. 

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot setReadAccess for a user with null id

Comment: please provide the code you're using.  You shouldn't be setting an ACL (if you are.)